# How can I check which RequiredFieldValidator fail?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Code :

```
Page.Validate();
if (!Page.IsValid)
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("ko", "<script>alert('Failed');</script>");
    return;
}
```

on this controls, some validator fails! How can I check which one? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a collection of validators and check which is not valid

```
foreach (var item in Validators)
{
     if (!((IValidator)item).IsValid)
     {
          //do something
      }
 }
```